# sql : select query without duplicate data

Tags: sql, select, crystal-reports

```
select ft.id, ft.qty, st.data from first_table ft
left outer join second_table st on ft.id = st.id
where ft.id = '1abc'
```

I have two tables. Schemas of those tables are as follows

No 1 table schema

| Id | Desc | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1abc | One | 3 |
| 1abc | two | 6 |

No 2 table schema

| Id | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1abc | 12ab |
| 1abc | 23ab |
| 1abc | z99c |

The data show wrongly after I join query

| Id | Desc | Qty | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1abc | One | 3 | 12ab |
| 1abc | two | 6 | 12ab |
| 1abc | One | 3 | 23ab |
| 1abc | two | 6 | 23ab |
| 1abc | One | 3 | z99c |
| 1abc | two | 6 | z99c |

Following is the correct way it should show in the crystal report. Please suggest me how should I do.

| Id | Qty | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1abc | 3 | 12ab |
|  | 6 | 23ab |
|  |  | z99c |

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to list values in separate columns.  This is usually best done in the application layer, but you can also use SQL:

```
select min(id), min(qty), min(data)
from ((select id, null as qty, null as data,
              row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
       from table1
       group by id
      ) union all
      (select null as id, qty, null as data,
              row_number() over (order by qty) as seqnum
       from table1
       group by qty
      ) union all
      (select null as id, null as qty, data,
              row_number() over (order by data) as seqnum
       from table2
       group by data
      )
     ) x
group by seqnum;
```